# Transparent drop down list when using jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm trying to use autocomplete from jquery-ui but the drop down list with suggestions is transparent so the text blends in with the page behind it.
This is what the script looks like:

```
var createAutocomplete = function () {
        var $input = $(this);
        var options = {
            source: $input.attr("data-otf-autocomplete")
        };

        $input.autocomplete(options);
    };

$("input[data-otf-autocomplete]").each(createAutocomplete);
```

I would post an example picture if i could. Anyone know what might be causing this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Did you include Jquery UI css file for autocomplete?

Comment: No i don't think so. Where should this file be included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include Jquery UI CSS file in your page before js script. Css file should be inside your zip file when you downloaded jqueryUI from their [site](http://jqueryui.com/download/).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a link to one of the built-in themes that comes with JQuery UI.

Comment: Hello there. It's not very helpful to reply to a question from 2015 and provide the exact same answer as in 2015. Please try to contribute to a question or don't do anything at all, because this causes old questions to be "bumped".

Comment: I don't think it is the same answer, because I was drawing attention to the fact that there are a dozen or so different themes, whereas the previous answer only gives one theme.